# Knitr and data.table

Tags: r, data.table, knitr

I have an automated report that i produce using knitr. i'm running across the oddest problem. I wrote a function that sums the data by month for several locations. when i run this function in R i get the following result (which is correct):

```
###NAME MONTH VOL
###1: TOTAL 1 13.00872
###2: TOTAL 2 11.62527
###3: TOTAL 3 12.71313
###4: TOTAL 4 12.67269
###5: TOTAL 5 15.05127
###6: TOTAL 6 14.61002
###7: TOTAL 7 15.43827
###8: TOTAL 8 15.22400
###9: TOTAL 9 14.91259
###10: TOTAL 10 15.83505
###11: TOTAL 11 14.97242
###12: TOTAL 12 16.34950
```

when i run this same function (no changes) through knitr to produce the report i get the following result:

```
###NAME MONTH VOL
###1: TOTAL 1 14.00872
###2: TOTAL 2 13.62527
###3: TOTAL 3 15.71313
###4: TOTAL 4 16.11338
###5: TOTAL 5 17.61269
###6: TOTAL 6 18.46945
###7: TOTAL 7 20.18851
###8: TOTAL 8 21.04382
###9: TOTAL 9 21.72287
###10: TOTAL 10 23.54272
###11: TOTAL 11 23.72971
###12: TOTAL 12 26.03293
```

i also have another table where knitr just prints non-sense even though the table has actual values in it.

Here is my session info:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages: [1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

other attached packages: [1] lubridate_1.3.3 xtable_1.7-4 shape_1.4.2 reshape2_1.4.1 rgdal_0.9-2 raster_2.2-12
[7] sp_1.0-17 png_0.1-7 data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] digest_0.6.8 evaluate_0.5.5 formatR_1.1 grid_3.1.2 knitr_1.9 lattice_0.20-29 memoise_0.2.1
[8] packrat_0.4.3 plyr_1.8.1 Rcpp_0.11.5 stringr_0.6.2 tools_3.1.2
```

***UPDATE***

i pinpointed the problem on at least one of the tables that this error occurs. The problem was the setnames function and the key merge feature of data.table.

when the merge happens R recognizes duplicate column names using a ".1" notation (i.e., if table1 and table 2 both have columns names CHEM then TABLE = table1[table2] has columns named CHEM and CHEM.1) whereas knitr is transforming them into CHEM and i.CHEM. to fix this, i originally used the code setnames(TABLE,names(TABLE),c(New column names)). but this didn't recognize the names(TABLE) in the correct order so i was renaming the wrong columns. but this error only happened when it was passed through knitr. when i ran this code through R alone it worked properly.  What is the diconnect between knitr and data.table?

I will work on getting an example code up but as it stands the code would need to be simplified to make posting an example helpful.

Comment: can you edit your question to add the information in your comments?

Comment: And maybe provide a reproducible example?